# Problem with WordPress output text ('esc_html' & 'wp_richedit_pre')

Tags: functions

I have a problem with output text. When I editing text in the WordPress control panel everything looks normal:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaIut.png

but when I output it to the html:

```
<?php esc_html( wp_richedit_pre( $_product->details ) ); ?>
```

It looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r81xE.png

What could be wrong? Please for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm ... strange. I looked to the file  '*wp-includes/formatting.php*' on the functions *wp_richedit_pre*:

```
function wp_richedit_pre($text) {
      // Filtering a blank results in an annoying <br />\n
      if ( empty($text) ) return apply_filters('richedit_pre', '');

      $output = convert_chars($text);
      $output = wpautop($output);
      $output = htmlspecialchars($output, ENT_NOQUOTES);

      return apply_filters('richedit_pre', $output);
}
```

Instead '*wp_richedit_pre()*' I used '*wpautop()*' and it works.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jiuiy.png

Thanks for the hint *Soulseekah*.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `$_product->details` contains what can be referred to as *post content*, and contains HTML, and you want to have that HTML rendered by the browser then you're doing it wrong.

Please refer to the [`esc_html`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_html) function and play around with it in a sandbox - you will soon find out that what the function does (just like the Codex says) is it escapes the HTML, i.e. transforms any special symbols to HTML entities, so these symbols are rendered as symbols and are not interpreted by your browser.

```
echo esc_html('<b>a string</b>'); // Produces &lt;b&gt;a string&lt;/b&gt;
echo '<b>a string</b>'; // Produces <b>a string</b>
```

So the short answer to your problem appears to be - remove the `esc_html` function from around the output.

Comment: I tried in this way (remove the 'esc_html'), but nothing has changed.

Comment: Can you paste a `var_dump($_product->details);` of your `$_product->details` here so that we can see what data is is contained there in the first place?